# Renew FormsAuthenticationTicket UserData

Tags: c#, cookies, forms-authentication

On my login page the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` is set as a persistent cookie with some custom userdata. Now I need to change this custom user data, so it contains one more parameter. When a previously logged in user visit the site the next time, I deserialize this custom userdata in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` but now I won't contain the newly added paramter.

Can I retrieve this paramter, without the user is required to login once again?

And if not, how to tell to the persistent cookie that it needs to be 'updated'?

Cookie set. userId is a new parameter:

```
CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
serializeModel.FirstName = model.UserName;
serializeModel.userId = model.userId;

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        model.UserName,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddYears(5),
        model.RememberMe,
        userData);

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);

faCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Cookie retrieval. Userid is the new paramter, and is `null` for previous logged in users:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

    CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
    newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
    newUser.userId = serializeModel.userId;

    HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using web forms or MVC?

It looks like your setting your HttpContext.Current.User correctly.  The problem may be that your by default that your controllers / views still thinks its IPrincipal and not your Custom Principal, So you can't access the new data you set.

You can cast it, or set it in a base controller like below.

```
// in some controller action
var firstName  = ((CustomPrincipal)User).FirstName


[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's MVC. It gets the right Custom Principal, but since it's just deserializing some data saved in the cookie, the newly added type isn't set in the serializing... So either the user shall login once again, or I would like to know how to update.

Comment: You've checked to see that the new UserId has been set and properly serialized in UserData properly before you encrypt it.

Comment: ... The UserId has NOT been set - that's the whole problem. For it to be set, the user needs to logout and login again and create a new cookie, and I'm looking for a way to not doing this.

Comment: You should be able to just overwrite the current forms auth cookie.  If this isn't working call FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); first then set the new Authentication Cookie. using normal Response.Cookies.Add(new FormsAuthentication(...etc)));